# Drawer header not overlapping StackNavigator header

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a DrawerNavigator header and a stack navigation. When the drawer is open, it dose not overlap the header. This is my code

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      path: '/',
      screen: WelcomeContainer,
    },
    Category: {
      path: '/sent',
      screen: CategoryContainer,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
  }
);


const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AppDrawer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft:
       <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Icon name="menu" color='#5c72b0' size={35} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingRight:80 }} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') } />
      <ChangeLanguage style={{ margin: 30 , padding: 30}} />
      </View>,
      headerRight: 
      <HeaderUserInformation />,
    })
  },
  Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
},
  About: {
  screen: About,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
})
```

I found different threads with the same problem. I tried to move DrawNavigator to the top level, my code become :

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: WelcomeContainer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft:
       <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Icon name="menu" color='#5c72b0' size={35} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingRight:80 }} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') } />
      <ChangeLanguage style={{ margin: 30 , padding: 30}} />
      </View>,
      headerRight: 
      <HeaderUserInformation />,
    })
  },
  Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
},
  About: {
  screen: About,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
})



const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      path: '/',
      screen: AppNavigator,
    },
    Category: {
      path: '/sent',
      screen: CategoryContainer,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
  }
);
```

Now the drawer is overlapping the header, however the header disappeared from the other components: If I click on an element on the drawer, for example settings, there is no header anymore on this screen. How can I properly fix this overlapping problem?

Comment: Your ```DrawNavigator``` should be the container, not the other way around

Comment: So the second code? And do you have an idea how to keep the header visible in the different components with the second code?

Answer (score 0):

The DrawerNavigator must be the outermost navigator in order for it to overlap the header, and each screen inside must be declared inside a StackNavigator, like below

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: WelcomeContainer,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Welcome"
        }
      }
    })
  },
  Category: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      Category: {
        screen: CategoryContainer,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Category"
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but left and right header component I created in WelcomeContainer are not appearing anymore, and the back button when I navigate to another screen also disappeared